# Can I get an onyx medal more than once?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I just got my first onxy medal for building 1000 fortifications in Horde mode.  Can I get an onyx medal again?  So if through the next several months of playing I build 1000 fortifications again.  Will the medal xp bonus pop?

Comment: I don't think you can earn an onyx medal more than one. Can you explain what you mean by "will the medal xp bonus pop"?

Comment: @jaminja whenever you get a medal you get an xp bonus.  So for the onyx medal I described above I got a bonus of 2500 xp.  So if I build 1000 more fortifications will I get the 2500 xp bonus again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain onyx medals can be earned more than once. I play arcade campaign a lot and I have earned the medal for getting 7.5 million points 5 times and I'm over half way to earning the onyx medal again for killing 1100 humans in beast mode. But i haven't been getting any extra for building fortifications in horde mode.

Comment: how do you know you are over half way through getting the onyx medal again?  Does the medal part of stats changed to show you where you are after you have received the medal once?